# How to get firebase generated unique id

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating chatting application.
When user login I want to store his unique ID which is generated by push.
How to get that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class there will be a method onTokenRefresh(). You will get refreshedToken in this method like below:

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

Comment: How to update particular child  Firebase suport = ref.child(uniqueId).child("status");
                                                suport.setValue("free");   is this will update tat status or create new ?